# Sum of PDF HistogramList bar heights is 1/2, 1, 2, 3, etc... depending on distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, histograms

I've noticed that my normalized histograms are not always normalized to 1. For example:

```
tlist = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[20, 5], 1000];
Histogram[tlist, Automatic, "PDF"]
dataList = HistogramList[tlist, Automatic, "PDF"];
pdfVal = dataList[[2]];
Total[pdfVal]
```

If you change the standard deviation of the `NormalDistribution`, you may see a change in the sum of `pdfVal` elements:

StdDev  >>>  Total[pdfVal]
1       >>>  2 or 5
2       >>>  2
3       >>>  1
4       >>>  1
5       >>>  0.5

I've noticed this with other histograms and other distributions as well (i.e. it is not specific to `NormalDistribution`).

Is there a way to force this to properly normalize to 1, or do I just have to do it by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "PDF" to "Probability" (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153799/46335) for a discussion of the two options)

Compare

```
Plot[Total[
  HistogramList[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[20, sd], 1000], 
    Automatic, "PDF"][[2]]], {sd, 1, 5}]

Plot[Total[
  HistogramList[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[20, sd], 1000], 
    Automatic, "Probability"][[2]]], {sd, 1, 5}]
```

[image]